# is it possible to remove a `:~` directory

Tags: linux, directory, filenames, special-characters

I can see a directory got created `:~` on my server

[image]

How to delete it as I can't even do `cd :~`
and I tried deleting it `sudo rm -R :~` but I can see a lot of things are inside that folder?

What to do to remove?
How to prevent it from being created again?

Comment: Did you do `rsync host:~/...` or `scp host:~/` or something like that?

Comment: @muru no i havent done anything like you asked but i tried `mv someFile :~someFile`

Comment: It is not a directory, it is a regular file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the directory execute something like:

```
rm -r \:\~
```

There's no way to prevent the creation of a directory with this (or a similar) name, as all the characters used in it are valid for filenames in your filesystem.

Comment: if I did this there is no harm to servers file right? because of its production server

Comment: thanks, it worked without affecting anything. i tried on my local machine first.

Answer (score 3):

To remove it,

```
rm -rf :~
```

Whether this is something you would want to do or not is something that only you can answer.  If the directory is unused (we don't know this) and if the files are backed up someplace else (we don't know this either), then it's more likely to be ok to delete the directory, but you should obviously investigate what the directory contains etc.

You possibly used `rsync` with an incorrect path as the destination directory to create this directory, or mistyped the path with some other application.  The tilde is not expanded within quotes, and not expanded if part of a variable's value.

In general, unless you know how [tilde expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) works, it's safer to use `$HOME` instead of `~` in the shell, as it behaves as an ordinary variable, and tilde does not.  If an application is reading a path from a file or from user input, it's up to the application to expand `~` and `$HOME` (it is therefore better to give the full path without `~` or `$HOME` to applications that don't do these types of expansions).

Comment: it got created in my production code directory. so i dont even know is it safe to remove this as when i try `sudo rm -R :~` `tab` then i can see lot of files and directories inside.

Comment: I've also done things like 'ls | head -n1', which shows just the funky file, and then pipe it to 'xargs rm'. It sometimes takes a couple rounds of experimentation to come up with the leading commands to produce just that single file.

Comment: Whether it's _within quotes_ or not makes no difference here. That `~` is not expanded here even if unquoted. The exception is in variable assignments (like in `var=:~` or `export var=:~` or in bash (but only bash) `echo var=:~`). Not sure how using `user@host:~/` in `rsync` would result in a `:~` directory being created though.

Comment: @ToddWalton There is no need to "experiment" with this directory name though, and note that `head -n 1` would possibly only give you part of a filename back if the filename contained newlines.

Comment: @ToddWalton, also, `xargs` splits on whitespace, so you can't even remove a file called `foo bar` that way. If you can produce a glob that only expands to the target file, it's easier to just write `rm ./foo*bar`

Comment: Good points. I don't think I've ever run into a filename with a newline in it, but I have had files with spaces, of course. You gotta make sure you know what you're doing! xargs has an option to see what it would do, printing out the command it would run, before you do it, which is *very* convenient when it comes to xargs!